# Как получить новый ip адрес по DHCP от роутера python

Tags: python, python-2.x, dhcp

Мне нужно получить новый адресс от DHCP сервера. Как я понимаю нужно удалить свой текущий ip и подождать, (а лучше запросить) пока роутер выдаст новый адресс. Подскажите как это сделать на питоне.

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно, что вы делаете на питоне. Но, например, на винде такая процедура выглядит так: `ipconfig /release` - освободить адрес; `ipconfig /renew` - запросить новый.

Comment: @defrag у меня убунту, а что вы будете делать если у вас несколько конектов к сети?

Comment: @defrag на питоне пишу тесты

Comment: к python, вопрос не имеет никакого отношения. Возможно вопрос должен звучать так: как выполнить команду ОС в python.

Comment: @SkiF ubuntu: `sudo dhclient -r eth0` - оcвободить eth0; получить новый - `sudo dhclient eth0`

Comment: как вы без Питона это делаете? Если не знаете, то отдельный SO вопроc задайте. [How do I renew my DHCP lease?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4014/3712)

Comment: @jfs я это делал через гуи убунты, а теперь мне это нужно сделать из питона.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa я подумал, что есть какая-то библиотека которая позволяет это сделать.